# Setting Up Restcomm on Ubuntu 14.04 (EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, sip, sip-server, mobicents, restcomm

I am completely new to Restcomm and currently experimenting with the application.

I want to setup a restcomm apps on my EC2 instance. I am aware that i can easily deploy Restcomm via the AWS Marketplace, however it only allows me to deploy on N.Virgina (whereas i want to deploy it on Singapore region)

After following the instruction described on this page [Installing from Github](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-installing-restcomm-from-github/)

I get the following message when i run

```
./start-restcomm.sh
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

When i try to access it via MY_PUBLIC_IP:8080/olympus i always get "Unable to Connect" message.

My restcomm.conf is as follows:

[image: Restcomm.conf]

If i have to guess, i think restcomm is currently listening to my Private IP instead of my Public IP. I am really new at this and hoping that someone can help with this.

This is my security group configuration, in case you need to know:

[image: Security Groups]

And ifconfig spits out this:

[image: ifconfig]

ps: I think someone really need to create a new tag "restcomm" for this kind of question.

Comment: Right, nobody has enough points so far it seems for creating the restcomm tag but that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing 5082 port in the security group configuration for SIP over Websockets. Can you connect to restcomm-management (Admin UI) correctly?

Comment: Let me do that, strangely enough if i deploy restcomm as a docker app it is run as intended.